# Css not loading with req.params or maybe something else

Tags: javascript, css, express

I'm very new to node, express etc. I've made a blog-app and i'm facing a problem. I'm using mongoose, node, express and ejs.

When i call

```
router.get('/posts', function(req, res){   Post.find({}, function(err, posts){
    res.render('viewpost.ejs', {
      posts
    });   }); });
```

Everything works perfectly fine. I got my posts and css is working as well. The problem is when i call

```
router.get('/posts/:posts_id', function(req, res){
  Post.find({_id: req.params.posts_id}, function(err, posts){
      res.render('viewpost.ejs',{
         posts
    });
  });
});
```

Post seems to be working but in console i got

GET /posts/posts.css 304 1.854 ms
And the viewpost.ejs looks like it's not using the css.

Server file `server.js`

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/css/')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/img/')));

viewpost.ejs

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="cyc">
  <% include ./partials/navbar.ejs %>

<%= posts %>
</body>
</html>
```

> So when i use route without req.params everything seems to be working
>   ok. When i call it with any param my css file is not working.

Comment: Yea!. use "/" (root) at the beginning of the path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` tries to load `style.css` from the same path where the HTML page is. So, for `/posts`, it will try loading `/style.css` and for `/posts/1`, it will try to load `/posts/style.css`. But the latter matches your `/posts/:posts_id` endpoint, so that gets called instead with `posts_id == 'style.css'`, which is nonsensical.

The solution is quite simply to make the link absolute:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue,but finally I solved it.
Do Following:
In Your HTML or EJS File write:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">`

in head section,it will work for both /post and /post:id