# 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "script.js" at path "_id" for model "Blog"'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to retrieve data from mongo by the id, it works well when, however when I add an external link, like a style file or a script file I get this error message.

> message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "script.js" at path "_id"
>   for model "Blog"',   name: 'CastError',   stringValue: '"script.js"', 
>   kind: 'ObjectId',   value: 'script.js',   path: '_id',   reason:
>   undefined,   model:

```
const express  = require('express'),
  ejs      = require('ejs'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  Blog     = require('./models/blog');

const app   = express(),
      port  = 5000; 

// mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/blog_v1', {useMongoClient: true});
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

  Blog.find({},(error, blogs) => {
    if(error) {
      console.log(`something went wrong ${error}`);
    } else {
      // console.log(blogs);
      res.render('home', {blogs: blogs});
    }
  });
});

// findById or find({'_id': 'id'})
app.get('/posts/:id', (req, res) => {
  Blog.findById(req.params.id, (error, foundPost) => {
    if(error) {
      console.log(error);
      console.log(req.params.id);
    } else {
      res.render('posts', {foundPost: foundPost});
      console.log(req.params.id);
    }
  });

});



app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
  console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out I had only files on the public folder, so all I had to do was to create a css folder and a js folder as it was explained here:

[Css not loading with req.params or maybe something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41723512/css-not-loading-with-req-params-or-maybe-something-else)